# RSS php reader with html select box

Tags: php, html, rss

I need to create a php rss reader with html select option. Xml file will be loaded into that select box, so when user makes choice on address from select box the rest of its feed will be shown. Is there any suggestion how to make this, 
thanks

Comment: this will help you very well http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_rss_reader.asp

Comment: Thanks Ivan Barayev, but it needs to be loaded from xml file instead of url, but thanks anyway

Comment: you can use this for your codes only you must change the post url in ajax and improve some codes ;)

Comment: ok, thanks, I will give a try ;)

Answer (score 1):

you could use AJAX to send a request to the server this would mean that you would create a PHP file in the directory which would be in this format

```
<?php
$_GET xml from select and other documents 
carry out checks and set XML according 
echo new XML
?>
```

then when the content box needs to be updating a JavaScript function that would look like this would be used

```
function onEvent(){
    url = "phpscriptname.php?"+values;
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        getElementByID(select) = request.innerHTMl().toXml(); //toXml is not a function see other Stack overflow question to solve this problem
    request.open("GET",url,true);
    request.send();
```

this is a rough answer that shows how it is done research into AJAX, JavaScript and possible PHP will be required